# How can you print a picture on part of page?

Tags: images, printing

I know it sounds stupid, but I can't figure out how to print a picture on part of a page with Android. The default printing dialog only allows printing on the full page, as far as I can tell.
I also have Epson iPrint which suffers from the same problem, as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

Comment: Guessing - download one of the many collage maker apps say to create a 4 by 4 collage. Take a pic of the paper you are going to print on and add that in three frames. In the fourth add your pic. Print

Comment: @beeshyams : I guess that would work, but it's not very flexible nor very practical. Ideally I'd like to be able to resize the picture with respect to the page using two-finger zooming :)

Comment: Yes , I understand and would be curious to know how it's done